# Swift: Circular UIImage with the circular Image upload UIButton on top right corner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

This is what I Exactly want. [image]

I'm trying by provide Corner Radius but it's not working properly.What is the correct way to Implement this.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried by adding the **relevant** code to the question. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please, we are not a code service. We are here to help you after you have tried something and it hasn't worked.

Comment: તમે પ્રશ્નમાં સંબંધિત કોડ ઉમેરીને તમે જે પ્રયાસ કર્યો છે તે બતાવી શકો છો. સ્ટેકઓવરફ્લો કોડ લખવાની સેવા નથી.ભાઈ સમજો. હા મોજ...

Comment: I understand. Is there any opening for IOS developer in iMobDev? @JayMehta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an image and button on storyboard like this

[image]

Connect image and button to your view controller, and set corner radius for them

```
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.layer.frame.width / 2
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.layer.frame.width / 2
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. Instead of the argue with the questions you just answer the question properly that's what I like. Thank you dear. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a `UIView` that contains a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton` and then give the `cornerRadius` to the `UIView`.It will be easy to implement.

For Eg.

```
 //oultes from storyboard
 @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var btnAdd: UIButton!
```

in view did load method of view controller, set the `cornerRadius` property with desired value.

```
//make sure mainView should be square
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = mainView.bounds.size.width/2
mainView.clipsToBounds = true
```